# Automactially set direction and text-align based on rtl or ltr languages

Tags: html, css, asp.net

We can set `direction` property for `body` tag to instruct direction either `rtl` to `ltr`. Similarly we can set `text-align` properties for individual elements.

Is there any way to minimize or centralize coding efforts to design an application which can support both `LTR`(English) and `RTL`(Arabic) languages. 
Its OK, I can write separate css for both directions, but what could be the best way to switch between these css(e.g, in master page load event)?

There also comes an exceptional case, like in English language I need first column of grid to display as `text-align:left` (it contains text), but remaining columns should be display with `text-align:left`, because that columns contains numeric values. Similarly the case will be reverse for Arabic language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target elements under `<body>` where direction is set to a specific value like so:

```
body span { text-align: left } /* default value */
body[direction="rtl"] span { text-align: right } /* override for rtl languages */
```

However if you have a lot of elements using text-align, this can get tiresome. Perhaps you could make a class for `text-align` using the same method:

```
.aligned { text-align: left }
body[direction="rtl"] .aligned { text-align: right }
```

Finally, for more complex situations you may find [RTLCSS](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/rtlcss) useful:

> RTLCSS is a framework for converting Left-To-Right (LTR) Cascading
>   Style Sheets(CSS) to Right-To-Left (RTL).

Comment: Thanks @daylan, close enough what I am looking for. It seems that I would not have to create separate css files for RTL and LTR, I can write css design in one file with right and left alignments based on attribute selector.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `text-align: start` or `text-align: end` then it will automatically do this:

> `start`
> The same as left if direction is left-to-right and right if direction is right-to-left.

> `end`
> The same as right if direction is left-to-right and left if direction is right-to-left.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Answer (score 0):

You can develop new code to act automatically based on html direction with `*-inline-*` css rules. There is a [website](https://www.bicss.net/) helping you convert your `CSS` code to such styles, but your `writing-mode` should be horizontal.